# Writing javascript that's efficient for the MVC4 bundling script optimizer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

A desirable construct for writing any sort of code is an enumeration, e.g.

```
var statuses = {
    none: 0,
    inprogress: 1,
    delayed: 2,
    complete: 3
};

.. 

if (status === statuses.inprogress) {
    ...
}
```

Google Closure compiler with advanced optimizations allows annotating such things with `@const` to direct it to optimize them and will replace the references with literals in the compiled code.

Is there any similar such directive for the minifier used by `System.Web.Optimization`? It definitely doesn't understand that these are constants, and when used extensively, can add a lot of unnecessary overhead. It would be nice to be able to write code that's both good and compressible.

Generally speaking I can't find any information at all about what (if any) directives might exist for the ASP.NET optimizer..

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how exactly Google Closure compiler does this replacement. Are you saying that `statuses.inprogress` will be replaced with `1` or that just `statuses` would be replaced with the entire object and then `inprogress` would be referenced off that?

Comment: statuses.inprogress will be replaced with `1` and the whole `statuses` object would be optimized away as a consequence.

Comment: ... and it also throws an error if you try to change a `@const` after it's initial assignment